# Tajo: Does tsql need Hadoop?

Tags: analytics, apache-tajo

I know Tajo requires Hadoop to be installed first. But I am not very sure bin/tsql. Is Hadoop required for tsql to run? If so, is there any plan to make it lighter? Any insight/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a PMC member of Apache Tajo. Thank you for your interest in Apache Tajo.

Currently, Apache Tajo requires Hadoop 2.2 or higher because Tajo depends on some Hadoop libraries. In other words, Tajo just needs an unpacked Hadoop distribution rather than a running Hadoop cluster. So, without a running Hadoop cluster, you can launch a Tajo cluster with local file system or Amazon S3 if you set `HADOOP_HOME` environment variable to your shell.

Tajo team has a plan to make its Hadoop dependency lighter. After we do so, you could easily deploy and use bin/tsql or Tajo cluster with your storage.